# How can we know which consumer get the message from queue on JMS?

Tags: java, jms

I would like to know how can we tell which consumer will get the message from queue in case we have multiple consumers at JMS queue?
for example, if we have 1 producer and 3 consumer (and 1 queue), how can i know which consumer gonna get the message?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways of comm with messaging: point-to-point and publish-subscribe.

In p2p there is only 1 consumer. in pub/sub the message is published to multiple subscribers and the subsribers can selectively process the messages using filters. For more details read the [3.5.2   Message Selectors section](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/jms/tutorial/1_3_1-fcs/doc/prog_model.html) in jms tutorial.

Comment: So only one consumer can use a receive() method on particular queue? what if another consumer will try to receive() from the same queue as well?

Comment: The behavior is not specified by the spec when multiple consumers receive() from the same queue. So it is JMS provider dependent